# tikzcd: distortion from large nodes

Tags: tikz-cd

I have the following piece of tikz-cd code where the large node in the middle is making that column larger than the others, resulting in distortion:

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={4em,between origins},row sep={2.5em,between origins}]
    &&& {(x+_{Lb}y)+_{L_c}z} \\
    && {x+_{Lb}y} \\
    & x && y && z \\
    La && Lb && Lc && Ld
    \arrow[from=4-3, to=3-4]
    \arrow[from=4-5, to=3-4]
    \arrow[from=4-5, to=3-6]
    \arrow[from=4-7, to=3-6]
    \arrow[from=4-1, to=3-2]
    \arrow[from=4-3, to=3-2]
    \arrow[from=3-2, to=2-3]
    \arrow[from=3-4, to=2-3]
    \arrow[from=2-3, to=1-4]
    \arrow["\lrcorner"{anchor=center, pos=0.125, rotate=-45}, draw=none, from=2-3, to=4-3]
    \arrow["\lrcorner"{anchor=center, pos=0.125, rotate=-45}, draw=none, from=1-4, to=3-4]
    \arrow[from=3-6, to=1-4]
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

It's rendering this picture in beamer:

[image]

Originally I had a tremendous distortion, the added *between origins* option was to fix that, but columns are still distorting their sizes.

Is there a fix?

Comment: You are just too generous with the `&`. For instance, why do you need two `&` before `Ld` in `La && Lb && Lc && Ld`?

Comment: Hey @user240002, thanks. That's because z must be in the column between Lc and Ld.

Comment: OK, if that's the goal then ` & x && y && z \\
    La && Lb && Lc && Ld` should probably become ` & x && y & z \\
    La && Lb & Lc && Ld`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you after?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep={4em,between origins},
               row sep={2.5em,between origins}
               ]
        &           &           & {(x+_{Lb}y)+_{L_c}z}
                                    &   &&     \\
        &           & {x+_{Lb}y}
                      \ar[ur]   &   &   &&     \\
        & x
          \ar[ur]   &&  y
                        \ar[ul] &   & z
                                      \ar[uull]
                                      \ar[dl]
                                        &&      \\
La 
\ar[ur] &           & Lb
                      \ar[ul] 
                      \ar[ur]   &   & Lc 
                                      \ar[ul]
                                        && Ld
                                           \ar[ul]   \\
\end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! Thanks.

Comment: From the spacing in the code I'd guess you used https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/ and later add the column seps? I guess my mistake was using https://q.uiver.app/

Comment: @DanielPlácido, I use standard `tikz-cd` package available on the CTAN. I format program code so, that I had a better overview over matrix structure of code.